# Call a pair of functions before/after the first/last instance of a class exists. Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a pair of functions `init` and `shutdown` as well as some class `RefTest`.

I need `init` to be called when `RefTest` is first instantiated and `shutdown` when the last instance of `RefTest` is destroyed. This can also happen multiple times in a program.

One implementation I've come up with is shown below. But this doesn't seem ideal to me (e.g. it is not thread-safe).
I thought about using `std::shared_ptr` and putting those functions in a class ctor/dtor but I can't seem to get it working.

**Is there any better way to do this?**

test implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
void init() { std::cout << "init() called" << std::endl; }
void shutdown() { std::cout << "shutdown() called" << std::endl; }

static size_t s_refCount = 0;
class RefTest
{
public:
    explicit RefTest()
    {
        if(s_refCount++ == 0) init();
        std::cout << "ctor()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~RefTest()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor()" << std::endl;
        if(--s_refCount == 0) shutdown();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
        RefTest t1;
        RefTest t2;
        RefTest t3;
    }
    RefTest t4;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
init() called
ctor()
ctor()
ctor()
dtor()
dtor()
dtor()
shutdown() called
init() called
ctor()
dtor()
shutdown() called
```

Comment: The "init" part is easy with the help of [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once). The "shutdown" part isn't really possible though, because you don't know when the "last" object will be destructed.

Comment: If you make `s_refCount`  a `std::atomic<std::size_t>` then you have thread safety and the semantics you want.  That is what I would suggest you start with.  I'm not sure if you can get the same behavior using any other way.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I'd also be aware of the various ways you can construct, like copy-constructor, move constructor, and their assignments as well.  Just keep that in mind too.

Comment: ^^ this. If you write a custom deleter, you must write at least custom assignment and copy operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this doesn't seem ideal to me (e.g. it is not thread-safe).

`std::atomic<int>` help solve this problem - but only part of the problem. It can make the counter thread-safe, so that you don't try to call `init`/`shutdown` too many times.

It will not solve the problem of calling the constructor a second time while the first call is still executing. (and then using a partially-constructed object)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this?

The generally accepted best practice is to assign exactly one job to each class.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>


// one class, one job
struct initialiser
{
    initialiser()
    {
        if (0 == s_refCount++) init();
    }

    initialiser(initialiser const&)
    {
        ++s_refCount;
    }

    initialiser& operator=(initialiser const&)
    {
        ++s_refCount;
        return *this;
    }

    ~initialiser()
    {
        if(--s_refCount == 0) shutdown();
    }

private:
    void init() { std::cout << "init() called" << std::endl; }
    void shutdown() { std::cout << "shutdown() called" << std::endl; }

    static std::atomic<size_t> s_refCount;
};

std::atomic<size_t> initialiser::s_refCount { 0 };


// one class, one job. Allow encapsulation to do the reference counting
class RefTest
{
public:
    explicit RefTest()
    {
        std::cout << "ctor()" << std::endl;
    }

    // rule of 5

    RefTest(RefTest const &) = default;
    RefTest(RefTest &&) = default;
    RefTest& operator=(RefTest const &) = default;
    RefTest& operator=(RefTest &&) = default;

    ~RefTest()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor()" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    initialiser init_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    {
        RefTest t1;
        RefTest t2;
        RefTest t3;
    }
    RefTest t4;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
init() called
ctor()
ctor()
ctor()
dtor()
dtor()
dtor()
shutdown() called
init() called
ctor()
dtor()
shutdown() called
```

Also note the non-violation of the rule of 3/5